# Keep names with apply

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, named

I have a named vector like:

```
mochila

r01 r02 r03 r04 
0   0   0   0
```

And a dataframe

```
data
        req_ID effort satisfaction
    1     r01      1           62
    2     r02      4           55
    3     r03      2           29
    4     r04      3           41
```

If I change a value manually, it keep the name

```
mochila[1] <- 1
mochila

r01 r02 r03 r04 
  1   0   0   0
```

But, for example, if I apply like this

```
myfun<- function(x){
  return(1)
}

mochila <- apply(data,1,myfun)
```

Result:

```
mochila

 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I lost all named position, Is there some way to keep names?

Comment: `mochila[] <- ...`?

Comment: @Frank OMG, some minutes to find my problem, it's so simple, so much thanks :)

Comment: Also, no need for apply. Just do mochila[] <- rep(1, length(mochila))

Comment: @csgroen It's an example of a function, in my real problem I need to apply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mochila[] <- expr` should work.

From `?Extract`:

> An empty index selects all values: this is most often used to replace all the entries but keep the `attributes`.